# Where is the JWT ID Token after I do Account Linking by Google-sign in for my app in Google Assistant?

Tags: actions-on-google, jwt, account-linking

I have enabled Account Linking by Google Sign-in following this method [Account linking with Google Sign-In][1]. It says I am supposed to receive a JWT Google ID Token with each call. From where I should extract user information. But in my webhook endpoint I am getting below information
`{"handler":{"name":"create_user"},"intent":{"name":"","params":{"AccountLinkingSlot":{"original":"","resolved":"LINKED"}},"query":""},"scene":{"name":"Main_AccountLinking","slotFillingStatus":"FINAL","slots":{"AccountLinkingSlot":{"mode":"REQUIRED","status":"SLOT_UNSPECIFIED","updated":false,"value":"LINKED"}},"next":{"name":"Main"}},"session":{"id":"ABwppHExhpgFArUhkwMtFsGCHLkgH9-Ixar7iSZFv9lwtKoilI2gN1Cuh-0FEvVN6f3x5v_BN8t0o4EhRB479w","params":{"AccountLinkingSlot":"LINKED"},"typeOverrides":[],"languageCode":""},"user":{"locale":"en-US","params":{},"accountLinkingStatus":"LINKED","verificationStatus":"VERIFIED","packageEntitlements":[],"lastSeenTime":"2020-09-18T21:57:48Z"},"home":{"params":{}},"device":{"capabilities":["SPEECH","RICH_RESPONSE","LONG_FORM_AUDIO"]}}`

So where is the ID Token? Please guide me.
[1]: https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in

Comment: Have you looked at the request headers for this token?

Comment: Hi Nick! Thanks for your comment. Yes I have a routine to dump all the headers to a file also checked cloud log. There is nothing. Can you please help me what should i do.

Comment: There's nothing in the headers? The guide says it should be in `conv.headers.authorization`.

Comment: I am using below code to capture everything 
` $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 
 // Log Request
 $myfile = fopen("tasklist.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
 fwrite($myfile, "\n");
 fwrite($myfile,"-------Request Recieved----------");
 fwrite($myfile, $json);
 foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) { 
    fwrite($myfile,"\n");
    echo "$name: $value <br>"; 
    fwrite($name. $value);
    } `